# Alternative to RedirectResponse

Tags: 8, redirection

I have a module that returns a redirect response in `hook_node_insert()`.

```
$url = 'announcements';
$response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url($url, [], ['absolute' => TRUE]));
$response->send();
```

I have another module that implements `hook_node_insert()` for the same content type. Since I have written redirectResponse in the first module, the `hook_node_insert()` implementation in the second module is not getting called.

Is there any other way to do it? Drupal 7 has `$_GET['destination']` and it works for Drupal 7.

Comment: Nothing's changed in that respect, `$_GET['destination']` still works as it always did. Well, `$request->query->get('destination')` nowadays but the mechanism is the same. `$form_state->setRedirect()` is also an option. You definitely shouldn't be redirecting in an insert hook, there's every chance you could break something

Comment: A redirect is better in the form, not in a hook_entity_insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, directly redirecting from a hook is something you should not do because it would not allow other hooks to be invoked, and it would stop what Drupal is doing.
In the specific, `hook_node_insert()` would also be invoked when a node is programmatically created from a module, for example in a `hook_install()` or `hook_cron()` implementation, or from a Drush plugin. In those cases, redirecting inside `hook_node_insert()` would just break Drupal core or third-party modules.

If you want to redirect users, the proper moment is after a form has been submitted. It is also preferable, because you can tell Drupal where you want to redirect users, and Drupal will do it after all the involved hooks are invoked.

You just need to add a form submission handler to the node edit form. Inside that, you redirect users with `$form_state->setRedirect($route_name)` or `$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url)` where `$route_name` is the name of the route (a string), and `$url` is a [`\Drupal\Core\Url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.6.x) object.